# If 'phantom read' involves two or more consecutive queries, what is it called when happening in one and the same query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, t-sql

Consider a SELECT query that needs to read multiple blocks/pages to produce its result. Updates committed by other transactions during the iteration of the candidate pages/blocks can cause a row to move from an already-scanned page to one that hasn't been scanned yet, so that different versions of one and the same row can appear in the result. Movement in the opposite direction can cause a row to be missed.

I used to think that these were called 'phantom reads' but extensive Googling suggests that term is reserved for phenomena involving multiple consecutive reads (i.e. effectively failure to lock the selection key range), not inconsistencies within a single read that are caused by the physical movement of a row in the wake of a concurrently committed update.

Does this phenomenon have a specific name that could be used for researching it in DBMS documentation and elsewhere? I'm specifically interested in Postgres and MS SQL Server.

*Note: the distinction is somewhat important because avoiding 'true' phantom reads pretty much requires key range locking or an isolation level of SERIALIZABLE. The exclusion of multiple row versions in one and the same query result might not require such drastic measures if the engine effectively fixes row versions for the duration of a query/transaction. This in turn is somewhat important because raising the isolation level can cause engines to switch from pessimistic strategies (queries might take longer but do not fail gratuitously) to optimistic ones that involve gratuitous query failure as a matter of course.*

For your reference, here is how [Wikipedia defines phantom reads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Phantom_reads):

> A phantom read occurs when a transaction retrieves a set of rows twice and new rows are inserted into or removed from that set by another transaction that is committed in between.

By contrast, the phenomenon I'm talking about occurs when retrieving a set of rows **once**.

Comment: [Halloween problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_Problem)?

Comment: halloween problem is when you do the update yourself an you don't wanna read the rows you already updated. Here, i think he's talking about an external update messing up already read rows. @OP, i fail to see the difference in the phenomena you describe, for me it's both phantom reads. I can attest that it has happened to me a couple of times, same row was returned twice with different values due to concurrent update. It was very cool

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: siggemannen is right - Halloween is an internal query consistency problem but the child with no name is a problem of isolation between concurrent transactions. The major difference is that the engine can detect and prevent Halloween problems by analysing the one and only query involved in it but it cannot do that in the case of the isolation problem.

Comment: It's just called a phantom read, I'm not sure why you think anything less than `SERIALIZABLE` will completely avoid them. Perhaps you are thinking of using rowversioing such as MVCC for Postgres or `SNAPSHOT` for SQL Server? Raising the isolation level does not do this, it is a separate setting

Comment: @Charlieface: Yes; the hoped-for result of my documentation research is that `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` in SQL Server and implicit MVCC in Postgres suffice to prevent the inclusion of multiple versions of the same row in the result of one and the same SELECT query.

Comment: Note that snapshotting has a different issue: write skew. You need to be aware of it when you are coding. https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/sql-performance/the-snapshot-isolation-level

Comment: An answert to ["Are missed rows and duplicate rows the symptoms due to allocation order scan or due to the no lock and page splits?"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/307757/183271) over on Database Administrators explains the two phenomena in copious detail.

Comment: I don't think the Wikipedia article is 100% accurate. For example, a concurrent update could remove a row already read and move it later in the index so it is read a second time. That is still a phantom read, as the row is inconsistently read twice. The DBA post also doesn't help you: it clearly points out that even index-order scans can still get phantom reads if an index key changes.

Comment: @Charlieface: HOLDLOCK semantics is sufficient for avoiding **duplicate reads**; that way the key change that would bounce the row forward into the unread area cannot happen. This is different from true **phantom reads** (records coming out of nowhere into the key range), which require key range locking a.k.a. SERIALIZABLE isolation.

Comment: `HOLDLOCK` and `SERIALIZABLE` are synonyms in SQL Server https://blog.51cto.com/ultrasql/1839580

Comment: Replace 'HOLDLOCK semantics' with 'holding onto locks for rows encountered during a scan until the statement is complete'. This is a weaker requirement than the range/predicate locks needed for SERIALIZABLE.

Answer (score 0):

In his superb book 'Pro SQL Server Internals', Dmitri Korotkevitch uses the following terms (p. 392):

> **Duplicated Reads**: This issue occurs when a query returns the same row multiple times. Think about the query that returns the list of the orders for the specified time interval, scanning the index on the `OrderDate` column column during the execution. If another query changes the `OrderDate` value, moving the row from the processed (scanned) to the non-processed part of the index, such a row will be read twice.

> **Skipped Rows**: This phenomenon occurs when queries do not return some of the rows. It could occur in a situation similar to the duplicated reads just described, where rows have been moved from the non-processed to the processed part of the index. Only the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, which locks the index key range interval, is free from such phenomenon.

A table on the following page indicates that duplicated reads can be prevented by `REPEATABLE READ` isolation whereas prevention of skipped rows requires `SERIALIZABLE`.

[SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide) does not make that distinction; it simply gives `SERIALIZABLE` or row versioning as a remedy for both phenomena.

As regards Postgres, it would appear that its MVCC logic should make it immune to these problems. The row versions visible at the begin of a statement certainly stay put in the heap, and changes occurring after that would not be visible to the statement.

But that is a separate topic: [Are missed/duplicated rows due to row movement possible under READ COMMITTED and/or REPEATABLE READ isolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76140686/4156577)