# Are missed/duplicated rows due to row movement possible under READ COMMITTED and/or REPEATABLE READ isolation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, t-sql

Physical row movement during a scan can cause **missed rows** and **duplicate reads** (same row appearing twice in the result) in SELECT queries under certain conditions. For MS SQL Server this is well documented in connection with the `NOLOCK` hint.

Some sources - among them Dmitri Korotkevitch and Paul White - state that only `SERIALIZABLE` isolation can avoid these phenomena, others indicate that `READ COMMITTED` or `REPEATABLE READ` are sufficient. One argument that convinced me is that a read can hardly be called repeatable if it can miss rows or return them multiple times, simply because concurrent updates change some field values. Also, what good would be `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraints on a table if duplicate reads could undermine them any time?

I'd like some clarity on the issue, at least with regard to MS SQL Server and Postgres, but I would like it to be somewhat definitive and not based purely on *opinion* as pretty much everything that weeks of research have turned up so far (on paper and on the 'Net).

Experiencing/reproducing the phenomena under `READ COMMITTED` or `REPEATABLE READ` would certainly clinch it, but Google only turned up several *challenges* to find such repros. Explicit statements in DBMS documentation or by the DBMS developers would certainly clinch it as well, as would wording from the SQL standards and associated documents.

So: can missed rows and/or duplicated reads occur under `READ COMMITTED` or `REPEATABLE READ` isolation?

Note: the **phantom read** commonly cited in explanations for the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level is an entirely different phenomenon and not of interest here. See [If 'phantom read' involves two or more consecutive queries, what is it called when happening in one and the same query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76127925/4156577), which seeks to clarify the terms and also has links to further sources/discussions.

*Clarification: this question concerns a row getting missed or multiple versions of it being contained in a result set because of concurrent changes to its attributes, *not* due to concurrent insertions or deletions.*

Comment: I think if SQL Server could miss or duplicate rows by default, no matter how edge-case the situation, it wouldn't be fit for purpose.

Comment: @Stu Much as I admire your sentiment, `READ COMMITTED` isolation is known to have serious issues with missing and duplicate rows https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-committed-isolation-level

Comment: That's a good article series and remiss of me to not realise I've seen it before; it does kind of boil down to the interperetation of what a *point-in-time* actually is or should be, the potential for these phenomena occuring is highly coupled to the concurrent tasks and presumaby a certain amount of chance. Clearly it's possible to occur but might be challenging to reliably reproduce such a scenario without artificially creating a non-real world situation.

Comment: Paul White's article *claims* that READ COMMITTED is subject to missed rows and duplicated reads, but it does not contain any corroboration or substantiation whatsoever. We all know where Paul stands on the issue, so I'd take this article with a grain of salt. Stuffing multiple queries into a single statement is a good way of demonstrating why even a single statement might need to be wrapped in a transaction but it is not relevant to the topic at hand. As regards potential staleness: that is quite different from *multiple versions of the same row* in the result of a single, elementary SELECT.

Comment: @DarthGizka while doing your research - have you possibly came across a description of a scenario when the missed rows phenomena applies to an UPDATE case? I mean one session is doing UPDATE that causes index scan with U locks, while other session relocates a single row - causing this row to miss the update operation?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek: I cannot specifically remember repro cases using UPDATE (or SELECT with UPDLOCK), but the only difference to repro cases for plain SELECT should be that locks are held longer. The underlying record selection should have exactly the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer is SQL Server specific.**

For the locking implementation of read committed locks are generally acquired and released as the data is read. This provides scope for both missed rows and duplicate reads during a single scan. For repeatable read locks are acquired as data is read  and released at transaction end. This provides scope for missed rows during a single scan.

> DBMS documentation or by the DBMS developers would certainly clinch it

See the articles on [read committed locking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/read-committed-isolation-level) and [repeatable read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/repeatable-read-isolation-level) by Craig Freedman on the SQL Server team - though TBH Paul White is one of *the most* credible sources on SQL Server.

In the repeatable read article I would draw your attention to the following quote

> These locks do not protect rows that have not yet been scanned from
> updates or deletes and do not prevent the insertion of new rows amid
> the rows that are already locked.

---

> Experiencing/reproducing the phenomena under READ COMMITTED or
> REPEATABLE READ would certainly clinch it.

There are some repros in the above links. A different one below for the double clinch.

### Setup (make sure to re-run this each time to put the table back into the expected initial state)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.T1

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
(
Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
Filler Char(8000) NULL,
DateModified DATETIME2,
INDEX IX_DateModified (DateModified)
)

GO

INSERT dbo.T1(Id, DateModified)
SELECT Id, DATEADD(DAY,Id, '2021-01-01') 
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8)) V(Id)
```

### Update query

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE dbo.T1 SET DateModified = DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, DateModified) WHERE Id = 7;

SELECT 'Start off the Repeatable Read SELECT query in a different connection within one minute'
RAISERROR ('', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00'

UPDATE dbo.T1 SET DateModified = SYSUTCDATETIME() WHERE Id = 1;

COMMIT
```

### Select query

```
set transaction isolation level repeatable read

SELECT Id, DateModified
FROM dbo.T1
ORDER BY DateModified DESC
```

Results (after one minute wait)

| Id | DateModified |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 2021-01-09 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 7 | 2021-01-08 00:01:00.0000000 |
| 6 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 5 | 2021-01-06 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 4 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 3 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 2 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00.0000000 |

Notice that the result only has 7 rows. The execution plan for the `SELECT` had not got as far as reading the row with `ID` of `1` when that was updated and moved in the index to after the point the `SELECT` had already read up to (with a backwards ordered scan so moving after means it is missed).

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of result I was hoping for. The repro code worked like a charm, both yours and Craig Freedman's.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding SQL Server:**

`READ COMMITTED` isolation is known to have serious issues with missing and duplicate rows, this is why RCSI is often recommended for new work. For example Paul White outlines the issues [in his series](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-committed-isolation-level).

The primary issue in this isolation level is that a row could be read, then deleted and moved by a concurrent update, then read again.

Having said that, this phenomenon is not as common as you might imagine, primarily because it's unusual to be modifying a primary key in the first place. It also can only happen if a scan is happening on an index, and an update happens around it, which is not that common.

Also, page-level locking (which is a pretty common) has a higher granularity, and `U` locks are used for updates which are not released if they are combined into a `UIX` lock.

> a read can hardly be called repeatable if it can miss rows or return them multiple times, simply because concurrent updates change some field values.

You misunderstand what "repeatable" in `REPEATABLE READ` means here. Repeatable means that once a row has been read, it cannot be changed by another concurrent query. It does *not* mean that the query *as a whole* is repeatable. To put it another way: inserts and deletes *ahead* of the scan are allowed, but anything previously read is blocked.

So the difference between these two isolation levels is whether a read query will release locks once it has read data or not.

You also seem to be labouring under a misunderstanding in how locking works when updating a key column. When you update a column which is not the clustering key then a lock is taken on the clustering key, not on the key of the index being read. But when an update is made to the clustering key itself then it effectively becomes an insert/delete pair. In other words, there is no major difference between inserts, updates and deletes when it comes to locking, they are all susceptible to the same phenomena.

> what good would be `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraints on a table if duplicate reads could undermine them any time?

Isolation levels are always a matter of risk appetite. The data once at rest is not problematic, it is only the *isolation* of different queries that is changed.

For example, you might decide you want to do a joined update on `OrderHeader` rows at `READ COMMITTED` isolation. You don't care if someone deletes or modifies your row after you did, so why not?

But when you want to do an `INSERT` to `OrderDetail`, joining `OrderHeader` in the process, you don't want parent (FK) `OrderHeader` rows to disappear after having read them, so you use `REPEATABLE READ`. The `SERIALIZABLE` level is overkill here, because no-one is changing the primary key.

Then you might decide to enforce a complex multi-table constraint using a procedure or trigger, and in the interests of consistency you wish to enforce complete isolation of all queries involved. So you would use `SERIALIZABLE`.

You might even have different locking hints per table reference in a single query. The point is: think about your locking and choose what it is you want to enforce.

> I would like it to be somewhat definitive and not based purely on opinion

There is a quite lengthy and clear document by Microsoft on locking and isolation levels [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#database-engine-isolation-levels).

Again, `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` isolation (different from `SNAPSHOT`) is recommended for new work, and this is the default isolation in Azure SQL Server. This uses optimistic concurrency, so avoids almost all of the issues with the other levels. `SERIALIZABLE` is very heavy on locking, so if you can avoid it then do so. Be aware that the snapshot levels have issues with write skew, which can be avoided if you code carefully.

---

**Regarding PostgreSQL:**

The Posgres documenation has quite a comprehensive writeup on [locking and isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html). I'm not very knowledgable on it.

But I do know that Postgres by default uses row-versioning (similar to `SNAPSHOT` in SQL Server), and this always applies when using `READ COMMITTED` or `REPEATABLE READ`, so most of the issues with that level do not happen. There is only write skew to worry about.

Comment: You are completely right in stating that REPEATABLE READ does not guarantee a stable (repeatable) result set, only that the rows do not change value when read repeatedly. However, the phenomena under discussion are caused precisely by concurrent value changes in pre-existing rows, not insertions/deletions. Hence REPEATABLE READ should preclude duplicate reads a priori.

Comment: An update to an index key column is treated as a delete/insert pair (which if you think about it, makes sense because the row is being moved) so it comes to the same thing.

Comment: Even if row movement  boils down to a delete/insert pair at the physical level, the question is which behaviour the engine must guarantee at the logical level. And then it needs to go and buy all the locks it needs to make that happen. BTW, thank you for your comprehensive answer. My head is still spinning and I still haven't done all the homework yet that you have ordered. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server documentation states explicitly that `SERIALIZABLE` isolation or row versioning is required to avoid missed rows (can't believe I missed this!). The information is in the [Transaction locking and row versioning guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide):

> **Missing and double reads caused by row updates**
>
> - Missing a updated row or seeing an updated row multiple times
>
>   Transactions that are running at the READ UNCOMMITTED level do not issue shared locks to prevent other transactions from modifying data read by the current transaction. Transactions that are running at the READ COMMITTED level do issue shared locks, but the row or page locks are released after the row is read. In either case, when you are scanning an index, if another user changes the index key column of the row during your read, the row might appear again if the key change moved the row to a position ahead of your scan. Similarly, the row might not appear if the key change moved the row to a position in the index that you had already read. To avoid this, use the SERIALIZABLE or HOLDLOCK hint, or row versioning. For more information, see [Table Hints (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table).

Missed rows due to page splits are dealt with as well:

> - Missing one or more rows that were not the target of update
>
>   When you are using READ UNCOMMITTED, if your query reads rows using an allocation order scan (using IAM pages), you might miss rows if another transaction is causing a page split. This cannot occur when you are using read committed because a table lock is held during a page split and does not happen if the table does not have a clustered index, because updates do not cause page splits.